# Potential Reasons for Fault on RS-485 Transceiver

Tags: rs485, signal-integrity, modbus, maxim

I am working with the [MAX3441](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max3440e-max3444e.pdf) RS-485 transceiver, but I have run into faults with the three transceivers I have tested, so I am wondering if anyone can shed some insight on potential reasons for the faults, or if my chips are damaged, which I am hesitant to declare.

The faults I am running into are:

1. The Fault pin on the transceiver being consistently high
2. The logic level of the receiver output pin from the transceiver is present but low.  It's low enough that the MCU's UART will not recognize the logic level for an interrupt
3. The input differential voltage on A and B to the transceiver does not exceed 200mV

Below is a picture of my circuit.  The only thing not pictured is a 0.1uF cap from 5VCC to GND next to the transceiver.  I have seen similar solutions work, so I'm not sure where the glaring issue is.
[image]

I am trying to test functionality of the circuit, so I pulled RE down to GND and I have A and B wired to a USB to RS-485 converter while sending characters over the connection.  I have used this converter to communicate with a Modbus peripheral and an RS-485 eval kit, so I am sure it can send the proper logic levels.  I have also soldered an RS-485 transceiver from the batch I received onto an SOIC DIP adapter, just in case my setup was frying the chip, but the same faults remained.

Based on this table from the datasheet, it seems the low RO is due to a low-input differential voltage, but I'm not sure how to remedy that since it seems the devices I am using to send signals work otherwise.
[image]

Comment: What are the actual voltages (all pins)? Should you have pullup/downs to bias the line when undriven? Why is DE/RE open?

Comment: I've no idea if [this paper is helpful](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt514/slyt514.pdf?ts=1699220254386&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). But it discusses ` failsafe biasing`.

Comment: If the voltage between A and B is less than +/- 200mV, the fault is expected to be high. So, what is the issue? Also just connecting it to a RS-485 that sits idle is no different. The PC RS485 should be sending data constantly or it will just send a character and go idle, so is this about not detecting the fault go low? Or maybe you don't have a ground wire between PC RS485 and MAX3441 so fault is high due to exceeding common mode voltage.

Comment: Have you tested/removed the TVS diodes? What else can make a link from A or B to GND?

Comment: I don't understand topic 2. What has the receiver output to do with a MCU interrupt?

Comment: @TimWilliams 1/Fault and 8/VCC are 4.96, 2/RO fluctuates just below 3V, 3/RE is tied to ground, 4/DI is zero because I am not testing the DI right now, 6/A is 2.16V, and 7/B is 2.09V.  The datasheet doesn't mention anything about requiring an external pullup/down, so I may have taken for granted there was something internal, but I will try that since it seems like it might help.  I have seen some circuits with a pulldown on A

Comment: @periblepsis I will check this out, thanks.  It seems to suggest pullup/downs as well

Comment: @Justme I am constantly sending characters every 4ms.  I am grounding both devices together now, although I wasn't for the first transceiver I tested which may have been a problem as I took the qualities of a differential signal for granted.

Comment: @Fredled I just tried the setup without TVS diodes, but the conditions persist.  A, B, and GND go to a breakout header which I connect to the RS-485 transceiver with.

Comment: @Jens It was my intention to explain that the RO was not meeting the threshold for the MCU's UART

Comment: If your MCU is running from 3.3 V you need a diode or level shifter between RO and the MCU-RX input. Without it, the RO output driver fights the input protection circuit of the MCU and actually it seams to win.

Comment: Have you only measured with DMM, or do you have a scope as well? Most likely RO is oscillating due to the truly indeterminate level, and you're reading an average.

Comment: Replacing the termination resistor with a higher value removed the problem with the low input differential voltage, and therefore, removed the fault.  I will have to look into the theory behind the termination resistor because it looks like 120 Ohms is standard, but not universal